# How to remove all nodes & edges on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

After testing several cases on AgensGraph.

I try to new test. but undesired result returns.

How can I remove all old data.

Answer (score 0):

"DETACH DELETE" can remote all nodes and related edge.

```
# create (:v{id:1})-[:e]->(:v{id:2});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 2, INSERT EDGE 1)
# match (n) detach delete n;
GRAPH WRITE (DELETE VERTEX 2, DELETE EDGE 1)
```

When absence of "DETACH" token, node with edges causes error.